# A working Java 8 is required to run Solr?

Tags: java, solr

solr version is 6.0.0
When I run

```
>bin/solr -e example
```

error with

```
Java not found, or an error was encountered when running java.
A working Java 8 is required to run Solr!
Please install Java 8 or fix JAVA_HOME before running this script.
Command that we tried: 'java -version'
Active Path:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

my java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

and my PATH is

```
/opt/java/bin:/opt/java/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Before running solr, try `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java`

Answer (score 2):

I edit the bin/solr

```
116     JAVA=java
```

to

```
116     JAVA=/opt/java/bin/java
```

then it works!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue on 5.5, this link helped me: https://www.garysieling.com/blog/install-solr-ubuntu